# return value from goroutine to take average time taken

Tags: go

I'm trying to do a benchmark for some code to check how things are running.

```
func obtainData(ds DataSourceStr, number int, amount int) (totalTime time.Duration) {
    // runtime := time.Now()
    // var totalTime time.Duration
    defer wg.Done()
    //.Nanoseconds()
    // defer totalruntime :=
    // defer fmt.Println("runtime completed", time.Since(runtime))
    defer fmt.Println("startRoutine done", number, totalTime)

    for n := 0; n < amount; n++ {
        start := time.Now()

        keyArray := [10]string{"key0", "key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5", "key6", "key7", "key8", "key9"}
        var key = keyArray[rand.Intn(len(keyArray))]
        ans, err := ds.Value(key)
        elapsed := time.Since(start) //.Nanoseconds()
        totalTime = elapsed + totalTime

        fmt.Println("[", n, "]", "Request: ", key, ", Response: ", ans, ", Time: ", elapsed, ", errors: ", err, ", Routine:", number, totalTime)
    }
    return totalTime
}

//how to implement benchmarks https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go
//benchmark
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func BenchmarkDatasource(b *testing.B) {
    //take the main code and run a benchmark testing the average run time.

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())

    arr := map[string]string{
        "key0": "value0",
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4",
        "key5": "value5",
        "key6": "value6",
        "key7": "value7",
        "key8": "value8",
        "key9": "value9",
    }
    ds := DataSourceStr{
        Data: arr,
    }

    fmt.Println(ds)
    //get average run time of each
    // sum run time / total

    wg.Add(1)

    go obtainData(ds, 0, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)

    go obtainData(ds, 1, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 2, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 3, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 4, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 5, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 6, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 7, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)
    go obtainData(ds, 8, b.N)
    wg.Add(1)

    go obtainData(ds, 9, b.N)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I want to be able to take an average of how long these go routines are running. I've made a variable in the above function to do this, but I can't assign the function to a variable inside the go-routine to then sum it later / average it later.

How can i get the return value or average the time spent without doing that?

Comment: First, you can't use a benchmark correctly if you don't use the `b.N` value. Let the benchmarking code determine the amount of time taken.

Comment: Que! Currently the benchmarking seems to have a decent output - how would i implement b.N?

Comment: See for example here how to write benchmarks: https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go. A benchmark always needs to execute the code in question `b.N` times.

Comment: Awesome, will edit the post now with the change :D

Comment: @LeCoda `b.N` should control the number of times you execute the code under test, not used as a parameter to the function under test. But to your core question - why are you trying to do your own timing in your benchmark? The point of benchmarks is that `go test` calculates the execution time for you.

Answer (score -1):

In your scenario, i believe a correct way to return a value from a goroutine is to send it over a chanel. Make it buffered and in the main goroutine read values after `wg.Done()`.

Comment: Let me give that a try !